# mySQL to DQL conversion help needed

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have the following mysql query that works in phpMyAdmin, but Im running out of brain trying to construct a doctrine equivilent with the queryBuilder for doctrine/symfony2.

```
SELECT u.*, ur.*, r.* FROM users u 
LEFT JOIN users_roles ur 
LEFT JOIN roles r ON ur.roles_id = r.id ON u.id = ur.users_id
```

Please please please can someone help with the symfony2 equivilent and try to explain why the solution works so I can try to understand it better?

Im finding using doctrine as clear as mud once it gets more sophisticated.

(all entities are mapped properly and working with other parts of the application. Can display if needed)

many thanks

** edit to add relationships **

I think Im getting confused with the relationships.  updating the schema created a third table and I think Im mistakingly trying to include that in the query.

would someone please help me with a query that will return both the user details and their associated role data?

```
class users implements AdvancedUserInterface, \Serializable
{
/*......*/

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="roles", inversedBy="users")
     *
     */
    private $roles;

/*......*/
}
```

and

```
class roles implements RoleInterface
{
/*....*/

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="users", mappedBy="roles")
 */
private $users;


/*....*/
```

Comment: Instead of going through the relations (joins) manually just join in the relations mapped in Doctrine. Ie: "SELECT u, r FROM Entity\User u JOIN u.roles r". Where u.roles requires a xToMany in your User entity called "roles"

Comment: many thanks for looking. I have relationships mapped, Ill add them to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed this.

after much head scratching this is the query I came up with that works.  Id ignored the relationships as stated by [JimL](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1078488/jiml).

```
$q = $this
        ->createQueryBuilder('u')
        ->select('u.username, u.id userID, u.email, u.firstname, u.lastname, u.isActive, u.lastLogged, r.name, r.id')
        ->leftJoin('u.roles', 'r');
```